# Opening .doc, .docx with Sylpheed on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, sylpheed

I noticed that I can't open .doc, .docx with Sylpheed on Lubuntu. 
I need to select "Open with" and then type Abiword.

How to automatize this process since when I try to click again on Open, anything won't happen?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open gedit
2. Copy and paste the following text into gedit:

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Sylpheed Docs
   Comment=Edit Files with Sylpheed
   Exec=sylpheed %f
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   NoDisplay=true
   Icon=[sylpheed_icon_here].png`
3. Save the file as sylpheed.desktop in the folder

   **/home/[username]/.local/share/applications**

   Replacing [username] with your username.
4. Now left click on a **.doc**/**.docx** file and select **Proporties -> Open With** and select the app called **Sylpheed Doc**.
5. Whenever you open a **.doc**/**.docx** file, it will open with Sylpheed

Comment: Sorry, but I meant opening the .doc, .docx attachments received on Sylpheed.